# How to display Article Title in other region? - Drupal

Tags: drupal-8, region, theming

I am beginner in the theming of drupal site.

I've `seven regions` in my `theme block structure` like this : [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVD4C.png)

**Question:**
I would like to Display my `Article Title` in `Crosswise region` and other `content fields` in `Content region`.

**It's possible to display Title and body in separate regions?**

If it's possible, how can I achive this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in drupal to split the view between two `Block regions`